# What are the common pitfalls to avoid in a jsp application in terms of security?

Tags: security, jsp, session

I am starting to work on a Fairly standard Jsp application. (Jsp,Oracle backend).

The security of the application is important. So what are the common(also uncommon ) Pitfalls that I should avoid as a novice.

Basically, Its just a few forms to get user input and some session management to display data according to user roles.

This discussion could serve as reference to future users also.

regards

Answer (score 1):

As a start you should read e.g. http://advosys.ca/papers/web/61-web-security.html and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project
And don't try to reinvent the wheel by yourself. Use something established like Spring Security instead of writing your own role-management. Getting such things right is harder then expected.

Answer (score 1):

A common pitfall is creating SQL statements by joining Strings, some of which are provided by user, for example in form fields. Never do that; user could enter a value that would change the meaning of your statement. This kind of attack is known as SQL Injection and is very common.

To protect against it, always use prepared statements instead of manually constucting statements from strings.